# How to upload files like photos to ios app using appium

Tags: javascript, ios, typescript, appium, webdriver-io

I am new to appium automation. I am trying to automate iOS native app using stack: appium-webdriverio-javascript-jasmine.

**Environment info:**

- Appium desktop APP version (or git revision) that exhibits the issue,
- App Version: 1.20.2
- Desktop OS/version used to run Appium: macOS Big Sur 11.2.3
- Node.js version (unless using Appium.app|exe): v14.16.1
- NPM: 6.14.12
- Mobile platform/version under test: 13.3
- Real device or emulator/simulator: emulator xcode/appium
- Capabilities:

  deviceName: "iPhone 12 Pro Max",
  platformName: "iOS",
  platformVersion: "14.2",
  automationName: "XCUItest"

Appium CLI or Appium.app|exe: CLI

**How to upload files from photos to ios app using appium?**
App Flow for Upload:
There is a button for upload, which onclick/tap, opens the images in the photos app in iOS.

So far I have used push files but it doesnt work.
`driver.pushFile("../data/sample.png","");`

I am not able to understand what to pass in the second argument, according to my use case, this files needs to be in the photos app, so that on clicking the upload button, i can choose it for upload. How do i ensure this?

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter in the `driver.pushFile` method is the remote path (in your iOS device) where you want to push the file and the second parameter is the path to your file (which you want to push) within the project directory. E.g: `src/test/resources/uploadDocuments/abc.pdf`